# read text file in php and use its content to fetch data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, text

I'm trying to read a text file using PHP.
After I read the content I want to match the content with an existing table in mysql.

My text file has this content

```
           :mh2045
```

The file is a .txt file

I use the following php code to read the text file

```
            <?php
               $file =         file_get_contents("file.txt");
              ?>
```

How do I use the contents of $file to compare with the field "vehicleid" of table vehicle info in mysql

this is the php code for selecting records after comparing with content in $file

```
      <?php
       $servername = "localhost";
       $username = "root";
       $password = "password";
       $dbname = "sample";
       $file=file_get_contents("file.txt");
       @var =$file;

         // Create connection
          $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,             $dbname);
         // Check connection
         if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
         } 

      $sql = "SELECT *
                   FROM vehicleinfo
                   WHERE vehicleid =    (SELECT vehicleid 
                                      FROM vehicleinfo
                                       WHERE owner= @var)";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "id: " . $row["vehicleid"]. " - Name: " .              $row["name"]. " " . $row["owner"]. "<br>";
 }
   } else {
   echo "0 results";
        }
               $conn->close();
```

Comment: From where did you get @var?

Comment: @var seems to be the Problem. For Variables in PHP you use `$`. `@` is for Error Handling

Comment: vardump() $file, u will see ur variable content, and will find out how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

For Variables in PHP use `$` not `@`. `@` is for Error Handling.
With a `.` you can connect Strings, ist a bad Practice to write the Var into a String. And also use `'` rather then `"` for Strings. That makes your proccesing quicker, becouse the Compiler doesn't look vor Variables in the String.

```
$file = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$sql = 'SELECT *
                   FROM vehicleinfo
                   WHERE vehicleid =    (SELECT vehicleid 
                                      FROM vehicleinfo
                                       WHERE owner= '. $file .')';
```

Comment: now it doest compare owner's value in the database with the content of $file which seems to be an array of string says zero result altough there is a record in the vehicle info table where owner = content of $file

Comment: Do you get an Error Mesg? You Query might be wrong, try '`SELECT *
                   FROM vehicleinfo
                   WHERE owner =  ` $file

Comment: $sql = "SELECT *
         FROM vehicleinfo
         WHERE owner = ' . $file[0] . ')"; i tried this it says again trying to get non object property

Comment: if i use $file instead of $file[0] it says tring to convert string into array

Comment: Do you have Access to phpmyAdmin or similar? Try Your Query in there to make sure you Query is not the Problem

Comment: Ah I see you Need to add " or ' around the variable in the query, becouse ist a String: ` 'SELECT * FROM vehicleinfo WHERE owner = "' . $file .'"'; `

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the @var line and use following SQL query:

```
$file = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$sql = "SELECT *
                   FROM vehicleinfo
                   WHERE vehicleid =    (SELECT vehicleid 
                                      FROM vehicleinfo
                                       WHERE owner= ". $file[0] .")";
```

Comment: I tried doing it,it says,"trying to get property of non object in D :\wamp\www\display.php

Comment: insert `vardump($file);` and tell us what it says

Comment: string 'mh2045' (length=6)

Comment: the content of the text file is string

Comment: then you dont Need the`[0]` behind the `$file` in the SQL Query